# Locate the location for entering from email address

Tags: email, plesk

I have a simple Contact form, with 'Send' button', that send mail from an email to an email.

In the local host with wamp server i have done it and it's working.

I have used 'fake email program' to send it, I entered the from email in the 'sendmail.ini' file.

How can i achieve the same goal using plesk service as a server, where can I enter the from email address?

It sounds like a simple task but I have just spent over an hour looking for it.

> i have an contact.html form with php for serer code, what i am trying to do is to send the contact.html form details that the user has filled to an external email, In local host i managed to do it but know when i uploaded to server I am having trouble to locate the 'from email address field' (where i can setup the email address to emails that are going out from the site).

Suppose you own a site and some user fill the 'contact us' form, You as the site owner will receive an email from your site with the user details that the user filled in the contact form.

> This code is from my php file @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
>
> and by using 'wamp server' on 'my local computer' and external fake email sender program, 
>   I filled up this file with my 'email from address' (sendmail.ini) with this lines:
>    'smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com', 'smtp_port=25' and 'authentication' details: username= my_name@gmail.com And password='mypassword' for that email.

This is what i am looking for in 'plesk' server desk The location of that ini file where i can enter the from address, smtp_port and authentication details.

Comment: I may be naive here, but why the negatives?

Comment: I don't understand also...

Comment: *"I did this thing one way and it worked.  Can you show me how to do it this other way?"*  The most likely answer is "Write some code."

Comment: Should not get Down-vote as question makes little sense..

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this question is very unclear to me.  What's not working?

Comment: Sorry i really tried to Explain it well.. and plus i am not asking for code

Comment: i have an contact.html form with php for serer code, what i am trying to do is to send the contact.html form that the user has filled with details to an external email, In local host i managed to do it but know when i uploaded to server I am having trouble to locate the 'from email address field' (where i can setup the email address to emails that are going out from the site), please tell me how to even clear it more and i'll:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it with PHP and the Mail() function:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: MyName <' . $from . '>' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $html, $headers);
```

- $from = from email
- $to = to email
- $html = email body
- $subject =    email subject

Comment: I did that this is from my php file `@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);` and by using 'wamp server' on 'my local computer' and external fake email sender I filled up this file with my 'email from address' (sendmail.ini) with this line `'smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com', 'smtp_port=25'` and 'authentication' details: `username= my_name@gmail.com And password='mypassword'` for that email. The question makes more sense now?

Comment: In the last line I add to the headers, you can change MyName to anything you want, and the $from variable to the from email you wish.

Comment: But I don't understand something, You don't send the `$from` variable to the mail method so how does the mail get send? what about the smtp, port, user_name, password?

Comment: Ok it worked, My problem was '$from variable is sent in the headers' That's all:) thank you very very much.